# Best way to isolate values to the sixth "/" found in the cell (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have the following values in the cells in `COLUMN A`:

```
https://test/one/two/three/four/oliver/Safira
https://five/six/seven/eight/nine/Twix
https://show/the/text/again/please/Isolate/arrows/Sheets
```

And I would like to isolate the values that come up to the sixth time the "/" is found:

```
https://test/one/two/three/
https://five/six/seven/eight/
https://show/the/text/again/
```

I know I could go removing the values every time the `/` came up with the `RIGHT and LEFT + FIND + LEN` functions.

But this way the formula is very long, because I would have to isolate `/` after `/`. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample formula? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample formula:

```
=JOIN("/",QUERY(SPLIT(A1,"/",TRUE,FALSE),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6"), "")
```

- Split the URL with `/` with `SPLIT`.
- Retrieve the columns 1 to 6 from the splitted URL with `QUERY`.
- Join the retrieved values with `/`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

When you want to retrieve the values with one formula, how about the following formula? I think that there are several answers. So for this, also please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A6,REGEXREPLACE(A1:A6,"(https?:\/\/([\w.-]+\/){4})","($1)")))
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: In this format, there is no way to create an array with this formula, correct? Only works row by row?

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I added one more sample formula. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the support, when testing in another link format did not work, could you tell me what I need to change please? I want to learn to be able to use in other link examples ```https://int.soccerway.com/national/belgium/pro-league/c24/```
```https://int.soccerway.com/national/australia/a-league/20192020/regular-season/r53497/```
```https://int.soccerway.com/national/brazil/serie-a/c26/```

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer by including your replying. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Perfect Mate! 100%!